# How do I thread safe update record in MongoDB for a complicated value?

Tags: mongodb

I have a db as follows:

```
score:0
timeScore:86400
totalScore:0
time:1234567777  // Any time stamp
```

now every time the user votes up

```
increment($inc) score by +1
```

Then I update timeScore to be e.g.  `(86400 / nowTimestamp() - time + 1 )`
Then I update totalScore to be `(timeScore + score)`

e.g: for the final values after 2nd update:

```
score:1
timeScore:86400
totalScore:86401
time:1234567777
```

the problem is that during my external calculation, may be another user add +1 to the score and calculated the total and wrote its values before I even update my data so there would be data corruption.

Now how do I solve this or how do I make it Thread safe ?

Comment: Unfortunately MongoDB does not support transactions.

Comment: Can you not just use MongoDB's atomic lock on `$inc`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to use the mongodb `findAndModify` function, which allows you to make atomic updates, meaning that while your document is being changed the value cannot be updated by another query. Docs available [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Atomic+Operations).

You may also wish to look at doing as many calculations before you push your data to storage as this will remove the need to read then write.

Answer (score 0):

the one good way is Save With OptimisticConcurrency. Create a version with every collection with that thread safety can be implemented.